# Как закодировать строку , используя таблицу ASCII для шестнадцатеричной системы счисления более одного раза в Python

Tags: python, шифрование, hex, ascii

Дана строка "s" и количество преобразований  "n"

s = "Hey guys"

n = 2

Закодируем строку один раз

```
if n == 0:
    return s
elif n == 1:
    return ''.join([hex(ord(el))[2:] for el in s])
```

строка закодирована в 16-ричную систему счисления 4865792067757973

```
  H  e  y      g  u  y  s

  48 65 79 20 67 75 79  73
```

при n = 2 должно получится  34383635373932303637373537393733

Каким способом можно много раз закодировать символ (если так два раза)

hex(int(hex(ord('H'))[2:]))        '0x30'

вообще не понятно как получается строка

34383635373932303637373537393733

Объясните пожалуйста как надо!
Если можно закодируйте любое слово в 16-ричную систему счисления хотя
бы 5 раз

Comment: Почему бы не написать банальный цикл?

Comment: И вообще вы таблицу ASCII видели? У вас после первого преобразования будет много цифр. А у них у всех код в 16-ричном представлении начинается с `3`, так что в чём вы нашли закономерность именно для n = 2 я не понял.

Answer (score 0):

Код 4 - `34`, код 8 - `38`. Поэтому для 48 получается `3438`. Если сделать ещё одну итерацию, получится `33343338`. И т.д. Чем больше итераций, чем больше троек перед каждой цифрой.